# Acess control inside RadGrid Edit template using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, telerik, radgrid

i have three controls inside RadGrid Edit form
My objective is to multiply textbox1 and textbox2 and display result on TextBox3 using javascript

---

```
 function multiply() {
                         var TextBox1 = document.getElementById('TextBox1').value;
                         var TextBox2 = document.getElementById('TextBox2').value;
                         var result = parseInt(TextBox1) * parseInt(TextBox2);
                         if (!isNaN(result)) {
                             document.getElementById('TextBox3').value = result;
                         }
                     }
```

THAts code working fine when i use that code for the controls out side radgrid or radgrid edit template, but how to implement same code on RadGRid Edit form

Comment: What is question? Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

If not mistaken this is what you want ? 
Is it in EditMode="EditForms"

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="sm" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnItemCommand="RadGrid1_ItemCommand">
        <MasterTableView EditMode="EditForms">
            <EditFormSettings>
                <EditColumn Visible="false"></EditColumn>
            </EditFormSettings>
            <Columns>
                <telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                    <ItemTemplate><asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("A") %>'></asp:Label></ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server" onkeyup="calculate();"></asp:TextBox> * 
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txt2" runat="server" onkeyup="calculate();"></asp:TextBox> =
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txt3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("A") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                <telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                    <ItemTemplate><asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnEdit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit"></asp:LinkButton></ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" CommandName="SaveValue"></asp:LinkButton>
                        &nbsp;
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CommandName="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
            </Columns>
        </MasterTableView>
    </telerik:RadGrid>

    <telerik:RadCodeBlock ID="rcb" runat="server">
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function calculate() {
                var grid = $find('<%=RadGrid1.ClientID %>');
                var masterTable = grid.get_masterTableView();
                var gridCount = masterTable.get_editItems().length;
                var item;
                var txt1;
                var txt2;
                var txt3;
                var num1 = 0;
                var num2 = 0;
                var result = 0;

                for (var i = 0; i < gridCount; i++) {
                    item = masterTable.get_editItems()[i];
                    txt1 = $(item.get_editFormItem()).find("input[id*='txt1']").get(0);
                    txt2 = $(item.get_editFormItem()).find("input[id*='txt2']").get(0);
                    txt3 = $(item.get_editFormItem()).find("span[id*='txt3']").get(0);

                    // Reset
                    num1 = 0;
                    num2 = 0;
                    result = 0;

                    // Check
                    if (txt1 != undefined && txt2 != undefined && lblResult != undefined) {
                        num1 = txt1.value != '' ? parseInt(txt1.value) : 0;
                        num2 = txt2.value != '' ? parseInt(txt2.value) : 0;
                        result = num1 * num2;

                        txt3.value = result + "";
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
    </telerik:RadCodeBlock>
```

Comment: oh my god you used the contains selector... what if the id values were like "myid" "myid-2" and "myid-3"... something to watch out for